# Can I use escape characters in LIGO strings?

Tags: ligo, string

I would like to insert some special ASCII characters that I only know how to express as numbers. In Python I would for example be able to write the `SYN` control character as `\x16` since 0x16 is `SYN` in ASCII. Can I do this in LIGO? I would also like to write `\x0a` (newline) as `\n`.

The [official documentation for LIGO](https://ligolang.org/docs/reference/string-reference) does not mention escape characters

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, using exactly the same syntax.
For instance, in CameLIGO, you could write `let x = Bytes.pack "toto\n\x53woo"`.

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful, does any documentation about this exist? Perhaps it could be added to the official LIGO documentation I linked to above?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. I expect an output of `0a` from this call (since the ASCII value of newline is 0x0a, but I get something different.
```
$ ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack("\n")'
0x0501000000025c6e
```